# Translate Wordpress User Roles To "level_[0-10]"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to code something that is aware of specific wordpress user roles.
Does someone know the corresponding numbers for the roles below?

- Subscriber
- Administrator
- Editor
- Author
- Contributer

For example: who is `level_0`? Who is `level_1`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#User_Levels)

```
User Level 0 converts to Subscriber
User Level 1 converts to Contributor
User Level 2 converts to Author
User Level 3 converts to Editor
User Level 4 converts to Editor
User Level 5 converts to Editor
User Level 6 converts to Editor
User Level 7 converts to Editor
User Level 8 converts to Administrator
User Level 9 converts to Administrator
User Level 10 converts to Administrator
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article, its explains how you get all user rolls:

http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/get-wordpress-users-by-role/

If you set this in your function and request it, you should get all roles:

```
function getUsersByRole( $roles ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( ! is_array( $roles ) ) {
        $roles = explode( ",", $roles );
        array_walk( $roles, 'trim' );
    }
    $sql = '
        SELECT  ID, display_name
        FROM        ' . $wpdb->users . ' INNER JOIN ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '
        ON      ' . $wpdb->users . '.ID             =       ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '.user_id
        WHERE   ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '.meta_key        =       \'' . $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities\'
        AND     (
    ';
    $i = 1;
    foreach ( $roles as $role ) {
        $sql .= ' ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '.meta_value    LIKE    \'%"' . $role . '"%\' ';
        if ( $i < count( $roles ) ) $sql .= ' OR ';
        $i++;
    }
    $sql .= ' ) ';
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY display_name ';
    $userIDs = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );
    return $userIDs;
}
```